# How do I randomly create the number of drops?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have made the rain continuous by changing the position of each drop when it reaches one side of the canvas.

I can add more drops by adding more random positions to the xPosition and yPosition variables.

However, how do I make this happen automatically?

This is my code:

```
var xPositions = [random(0, 400), random(0, 400)];
var yPositions = [random(0, 400), random(0, 400)];

draw = function() {
    
    background(204, 247, 255);

    noStroke();
    fill(0, 200, 255);

    for (var i = 0; i < xPositions.length; i++) {
        ellipse(xPositions[i], yPositions[i], 10, 10);
        yPositions[i] +=3;
    
    if(yPositions[i] > 400) {
    yPositions[i] = 0;

    xPositions = [random(0, 400), random(0, 400)];
    yPositions = [0, 0];
    
    }
    }
};
```

Answer (score 1):

You could write a function, `addDrop` to add a raindrop in a random position, and then call that function a random number of times to generate a random number of raindrops:

```js
random = function(min, max) {
  return Math.floor((max - min) * Math.random() + min);
}

var xPositions = [];
var yPositions = [];

addDrop = function() {
  xPositions.push(random(0, 400));
  yPositions.push(random(0, 400));
}

for (var i = 0; i < random(5, 15); i++) {
  addDrop();
}

for (var i = 0; i < xPositions.length; i++) {
  console.log([xPositions[i], yPositions[i]]);
}
```